# How to convert a single String into an Array of custom objects

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a map with key / value pairs and a JavaBean which should get populated with that values  like that:

`BeanUtils.populate(bean, map)`

which works great. But there is one property in map which contains a single JSON String which i need to parse and convert to an array object.

The property in the bean looks like this:

```
private MyCustomClass[] customObjects;
...
public setCustomObjects(MyCustomClass[] customObjects){
 this.customObjects = customObjects;
}
```

So what i need is a custom converter which takes a single string from the map and converts it to an array. But unfortunately i could find a way to do this up to know.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Serialization and Deserialization. If you need it to serialize/deserialize a JSON string specifically, take a look at [this project](http://code.google.com/p/json-io/). If these do you no good, you will probably need to write some sort of parser and fill the objects with data yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but no. I'm not searching for (de)serialization. Iwill deserialize the String with Gson as soon as i found out how to write a custom vonverter that takes a single Strings and spits out an Array of my custom Object.